What circuit protection devices are needed for an automotive application?
I am designing a circuit for a automotive application which is meant to map voltage ranges between two sensors (ex. 1 sensor has an output range of 0-5V while the other has a output range of 1.75-7.0V). The basic components of the circuit are a opamp and a voltage regulator/reference to provide a bias into the opamp. This question is aimed more towards the power supply and any relevant protections for these two devices. I know automotive power can get very dirty and that protection circuits are necessary to account for this. I have done some research on the topic but cannot get a very clear answer and what to pursue. The devices/circuits I have come across so far are buck-boost converters, TVS's, and crowbar circuits.
My question is are all of these necessary? If I was to set up a buck-boost converter to 12V output, would this already handle any under/over voltage conditions? Are there any other dedicated devices which handle all of these protections at once? How do I decide whether I need to use a buck-boost, TVS, crowbar, or other related circuit-protection devices?

I would recommend looking to specifically automotive PMICs and looking at its application designs. Many chip suppliers for PMICs have good documentation for various applications. Right now, the way you are describing your design is unclear.

I would start with this app note: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/varistors/littelfuse_suppression_of_transients_in_an_automotive_environment_application_note.pdf and decide if you want to design for shall we say unlikely events like accidental 24V battery and load dump.

If your circuit needs a solid 12v supply, a buck-boost converter is going to be a must. I'm assuming you'll be powering off the vehicle's battery, and that voltage likely will swing fairly low and fairly high of that nominal 12v.
TVS diodes on any power/signal that comes in and any power/signal that goes out are also going to be necessary if you want any sort of reliability. Filter your search results for something AEC-Q101 qualified to have confidence in the TVS' ability to shunt the surges your circuits will likely see during operation.
For your last question on how to decide if you need any of those components:

you need a buck-boost converter when your supply is expected to range high and low of your desired rail voltage (e.g. a lithium battery could have a cell voltage of anywhere between 3 and 4.2V, but you need a solid 3.3V rail - the converter spends most of its time 'bucking' the battery voltage, but boosts when the battery is getting significantly discharged). If this circuit only needed a 3.3v rail, you'd be fine with using just a buck converter since the vehicle battery won't ever likely drop that low.
you ideally want to use a TVS diode any time you have a signal going off your PCB.
I've seen MOV's used for handling power line (think coming out of the wall) surges. They do really well at shunting AC.

